# vue how to add attributes to vcalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vcalendar

I'm using the [vcalendar](https://vcalendar.io/) for my `vue`-app. So far it works ok but when I try to add some attributes, they don't apply

here is my code:

```html
<v-calendar :attributes="attributes" :available-dates="availableDates" @dayclick="dayClicked" />
```

then I do this:

```
computed: {
  attributes() {
    return this.availableDates.map((date) => ({
       dot: {
         backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
       },
    }))
  },
}
```

but nothing happens and I don't know why. Can someone maybe help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to add a dot under all available dates in `v-calendar`.

`attributes` does not need to be computed. It should just be a data property that refers to `availableDates` (not mapped from it):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    const availableDates = [ new Date() ]
    return {
      availableDates,
      attributes: [
        {
          dot: true,
          dates: availableDates,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

Since `attributes.dates` refers to `availableDates`, any changes to `availableDates` is automatically reflected in the `attributes` binding.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-v-calendar-attributes?file=src%2FApp.vue)